# Rails: Sorting a query by params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using running a simple find all and paginating with willpaginate, but I'd also like to have the query sorted by the user. The first solution that came to mind was just use a params[:sort]

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/?sort=created_at+DESC

@posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => params[:sort]
```

But the problem with his approach is that the query is defaulting as sorting by ID and I want it to be created_at.

Is this a safe approach to sorting and is there a way to default to created_at?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I’d use a named scope for providing the default order (available since Rails 2.1).

You’d add the scope in your Post model:

```
named_scope :ordered, lambda {|*args| {:order => (args.first || 'created_at DESC')} }
```

Then you can call:

```
@posts = Post.ordered.paginate :page => params[:page]
```

The example above will use the default order from the `named_scope` (`created_at DESC`), but you can also provide a different one:

```
@posts = Post.ordered('title ASC').paginate :page => params[:page]
```

You could use that with Romulo’s suggestion:

```
sort_params = { "by_date" => "created_at", "by_name" => "name" }
@posts = Post.ordered(sort_params[params[:sort]]).paginate :page => params[:page]
```

If `params[:sort]` isn’t found in `sort_params` and returns `nil` then `named_scope` will fall back to using the default order.

[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/108-named-scope) has some great info on named_scopes.

Comment: If anyone else happens across this, the updated syntax for the scope is like so:  
  
`scope :ordered, ->(*args) { order(args.first || 'created_at DESC') }`

Method itself is still useful!

Answer (score 2):

In general, the way to supply default values for Hash and Hash-like objects is to use `fetch`:

```
params.fetch(:sort){ :created_at }
```

A lot of people just use `||` though:

```
params[:sort] || :created_at
```

I prefer `fetch` myself as being more explicit, plus it doesn't break when `false` is a legitimate value.

Answer (score 2):

The Ruby idiom to set a default would be:

```
@posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => params[:sort] || "created_at"
```

But the approach isn't safe. The paginate method will not bother with a parameter like `"created_at; DROP DATABASE mydatabase;"`. Instead, you could use a dictionary of valid sort parameters (untested):

```
sort_params = { "by_date" => "created_at", "by_name" => "name" }

@posts = Post.paginate :page => params[:page], :order => sort_params[params[:sort] || "by_date"]
```

So that the URI becomes:

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/?sort=by_date
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this idiom:

```
@posts = Post.paginate :page=>page, :order=>order
...

def page
  params[:page] || 1
end

def order
  params[:order] || 'created_at ASC'
end
```